# Why this solution of producer-consumer in Scala doesn't work?

Tags: scala, actor, producer-consumer

I'm currently learning Scala by the book Programming in Scala, 2nd edition. I tried to implement producer-consumer problem, using actors, but my code only prints:

```
Producer: new value: 0
Consumer #2: read value: 0
Consumer #4: read value: 0
Consumer #1: read value: 0
Consumer #3: read value: 0
Consumer #5: read value: 0
```

and then it hangs. I can't figure out what I did wrong.
Any help much appreciated!

Producer.scala:

```
package cz.zaoral.scala.actors.prodcons

import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor.{react, actor, self}

class Producer(
  val cycles: Int,
  val productionTime: Int,
  val consumers: List[Actor])
extends Actor {
  private var consumersConsumed = 0
  private var currentValue = 0

  case class ProduceNewValue(cycleNum: Int)
  case class NewValueProduced(value: Int)

  private val producer = actor {
    loop {
      self.react {
        case ProduceNewValue(x) =>
          Thread.sleep(productionTime)
          Producer.this ! NewValueProduced(x)
        case x => println("Unhandled message in producer: "+ x)
      }
    }
  }

  def act() {
    producer ! ProduceNewValue(currentValue)
    loop {
      if (consumersConsumed == consumers.length - 1) {
        consumersConsumed = 0
        if (currentValue < cycles) {
          currentValue += 1
          producer ! ProduceNewValue(currentValue)
        } else {
          sendToAllConsumers(EndOfInput())
          exit()
        }
      }
      receiveMessage()
    }
  }

  private def receiveMessage() {
    react {
      case ValueRead() => consumersConsumed += 1
      case NewValueProduced(x) =>
        println("Producer: new value: "+ x)
        sendToAllConsumers(ValueProduced(x, self))
      case msg => println("unhandled message in Producer: "+ msg)
    }
  }

  private def sendToAllConsumers(msg: Message) {
    for (consumer <- consumers)
      consumer ! msg
  }
}
```

Consumer.scala

```
package cz.zaoral.scala.actors.prodcons

import scala.actors.Actor

class Consumer(number: Int) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case ValueProduced(x, producer) =>
          println(this + ": read value: "+ x)
          producer ! ValueRead()
        case EndOfInput => exit()
        case x => println("Unhandled message in Consumer: "+ x)
      }
    }
  }

  override def toString =
    "Consumer #"+ number

  start()
}
```

Messages.scala:

```
package cz.zaoral.scala.actors.prodcons

import scala.actors.Actor

abstract class Message

case class ValueProduced(newValue: Int, producer: Actor) extends Message
case class ValueRead extends Message
case class EndOfInput extends Message
```

Demo.scala

```
package cz.zaoral.scala.actors.prodcons

import scala.actors.Actor

object Demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val consumers = for {
      i <- 1 to 5
      consumer = new Consumer(i)
    } yield consumer

    val producer = new Producer(10, 1000, consumers.toList)
    producer.start()
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found the solution myself :) I used actor method in a wrong manner. scala.actors.Actor.actor method is a factory method which creates and immediately starts new actor.

New Producer.scala:

```
package cz.zaoral.scala.actors.prodcons

import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor.{react, actor, self}


class Producer(
  val cycles: Int,
  val productionTime: Int,
  val consumers: List[Actor])
extends Actor {
  private var remainingConsumers = consumers.toSet
  private var currentValue = 0

  case class NewValueProduced(value: Int)

  private def produce() = actor {
    Thread.sleep(productionTime)
    Producer.this ! NewValueProduced(currentValue + 1)
  }

  def act() {
    produce()
    loop {
      if (remainingConsumers.isEmpty) {
        if (currentValue < cycles) {
          remainingConsumers ++= consumers
          produce()
        } else {
          sendToAllConsumers(EndOfInput())
          exit()
        }
      }
      receiveMessage()
    }
  }

  private def receiveMessage() {
    react {
      case ValueRead(consumer) =>
        assert(remainingConsumers.contains(consumer))
        remainingConsumers -= consumer
      case NewValueProduced(x) =>
        currentValue = x
        println("Producer: new value: "+ currentValue)
        sendToAllConsumers(ValueProduced(currentValue, self))
    }
  }

  private def sendToAllConsumers(msg: Message) {
    for (consumer <- consumers)
      consumer ! msg
  }
}
```

Note, that in case anyone would like to fit in this new definition within the rest of the example, some small changes have to be done in other files, but it shouldn't be a big deal.

Have nice day!

Comment: It's ok to post your answer as an actual answer to your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: Please note that the scala.actor package is deprecated and there is no reason for using it. You should take a look at Akka instead.

Comment: I would have answered to my question with comment, but you can't comment your question for 8 hours and I didn't want anyone trouble with reading the code while I already worked it out ;)